# How to restrict number of concurrent processes?

Tags: c#

My situation is as follow:

1. I have an application that can be started only a fixed number of times (less than 50).
2. A separate central process to manage other processes is not allowed due to business requirement. (ie. if a nice solution that involves ONLY the application processes is still acceptable)
3. I am using C# for developing the application and therefore managed solution is preferred.
4. I have to deal with "unexpected" cases such as the processes can be terminated by using TaskManager.

I am thinking of solution that make use of system-wide mutex. However, it doesn't survive the "Unexpected" cases very well in the way that it leaves "abandoned" mutex. If this is a good way, may I ask what is the catch of "ignoring" the mutex abandoned?

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to query for the process list and count the number of instances currently alive.  Another approach, more comples, would be to broadcast UDP and count the number of responses.  I have used this pattern for distributed scenarios related to job processors.

HTH

Colby Africa

Comment: Using the Broadcast UDP approach, does it mean that the "guarding" is not strict? I mean if the process is busying with something and answer too late, would it cause my calculation of active process inaccurate?

Comment: I would think of the process list too.

Comment: The way to ensure you respond even if busy is to have a another thread sleeping on the socket waiting for the broadcast.  The listener thread wakes up when a broadcast is received and responds.  Make sure the listener is a background thread so it will die if the main worker thread dies!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shared memory segment and increment a count each time an application is opened, and decrement when the application is closed. A more simple approach may be to use an interprocess semaphore which you alluded to in your question.

Comment: I have though of using shared memory approach but if a process is terminated, I cannot have that number decremented (the process is dead accidentally and no code is executed, or can there be any?)

Answer (score 0):

When a process is terminated via an "unexpected" event such as task manager process killing it should throw a ThreadAbortException. You should really try to wrap your mutex holding in some sort of try / finally that will allow you to release it as the thread is aborting.

I'm not 100% sure that's true but there aught to be some way to respond to situations like that.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the Process List approach, using [WMI.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404655.aspx) with *C#* may look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace WmiProc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementScope ms = new System.Management.ManagementScope(
                @"\\myserver\root\cimv2");

            var oq = new System.Management.ObjectQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process where Name='myprocname'");
            ManagementObjectSearcher query1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, oq);
            ManagementObjectCollection procsCollection = query1.Get();
            Console.WriteLine("process count:{0}", procsCollection.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: There will be some separation of starting times, such that letting too many processes to run at once is not likely. You'll have to test for specific behavior in your environment.

Maybe you can periodically check the process count from a separate (long running) process and terminate excess processes according to some criterion (e.g. newest).

Comment: About this querying process approach, if multiple processes start at the same time, would this method cause most processes fail the checking (because for every single process, they will "believe" many processes are started already)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could work with named Mutex-instances.

Use a personal naming-scheme for Mutexes, request this name and check the result of a mutex with this name already was created.

If you use a naming scheme with an incremental element, you can try all mutex-names ascending you incremental element, and count like this, how many mutex were created.

Needs some improvement on handling with released mutexes still, but that seems trivial.

```
class Program
{
    private static Mutex mutex = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);

        int count = Program.CheckInstanceCount();
        Console.WriteLine("This is instance {0} running.", count);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        Program.mutex.Close();
    }

    private static int CheckInstanceCount()
    {
        int result = 0;
        bool created = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            /* try to create a mutex with this name, 
             * if it does exist, another instance 
             * of this program is running
             */
            mutex = new Mutex(true, string.Concat(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, i.ToString()), out created);
            if (created)
            {
                // this instance is instance #i currently running
                result = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have also experimented this approach and the only catch is that .NET throw me AbandonedMutexException if I kill those previously started process by TaskManager. Is there any negative impact for that?

Comment: Well, here the .net framework does not complain about anything. What catches this exception? When does it raise exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add comments to an above answer, but from reading the above answers, and comments, it seems like you should be able to combine a mutex with the Process Instance check.

```
// You can use any System wide mutual exclusion mechanism here
bool waitAndLockMutex();
void unlockMutex();

// returns the number of processes who use the specified command
int getProcessCount();

void main() {
    try {
        waitAndLockMutex();
        if (getProcessCount() > MAX_ALLOWED)
            return;

        doUsualWork();

    } finally {
        unlockMutex();
    }
}
```

Note that the above code is simply for illustrative purposes, and the body for the declared functions calls can be easily written using .NET

EDIT:

If you do not want to go the route of counting the processes of interest, you can use global mutex for it. Not sure if .NET exposes that. But the gist is that you can acquire all the mutexes till the MAX, and in the process if you get a Mutex that has not yet been created or is ABANDONED, then you go ahead and let the process launch, else exit saying exceeding max count

```
void main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        int status = TryToAcquireMutex("mutex" + i);
        continue if (status == locked);
        if (status == success || status == WAIT_ABANDONED) {
            doUsusalWork();
        }
    }
}
```