# semaphore implementation for counting no. of instances currently running

Tags: c#, semaphore

I am working on multi instance application. Is there any way in c# to know that how many instances are running currently.
I used one peice of code to count the window processes of my application name but that is not a good way.

```
string fileName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
int count = 0;
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    try
     {
        if (p.MainModule.FileName == fileName)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    catch { }
}

MessageBox.Show("Total Instances Running are " + count);
```

Can it be done by using *semaphore* or some increment and decrement counter  that is incremented by one when new instance is created and decrement by one when a  instance closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`Semaphore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) helps you count down, blocking you when you get to 0. You could use a global semaphore, but you'll have to initialize it at a high enough-value and start counting down.

I think all in all, your own solution is probably the cleanest.

Comment: thanks for answer. Can u pls tell me some other resources except msdn.

Comment: Google? https://www.google.co.il/search?q=.net+semaphore&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: The problem with the Semaphore class is that you can't get the count without releasing it, which can produce some pretty messy code...

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie is there not any other way to do this  except semaphore.

Comment: See below: When your app starts, try to access system mutex "MyApp_Salt_1". If already exists, try to get 2, 3, etc until successful. Release mutex on exit. When you count, just count how many system mutexes exist using your naming format. Problems: 1. Messy leaving mutexes everywhere; 2. Holes in mutex structure will be left as instances terminate, so you never know what the maximum count will be - you'll just have to have a hard-coded upper limit. Possibly just as ugly as the Semaphore approach... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385497/how-to-restrict-number-of-concurrent-processes

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use shared memory? Of course you have to protect it with a mutex visible to all processes, but in this way you can store commonly used data among all processes.

I suppose you have to P/Invoke platform routine is order to create a shared memory, but it really straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Managing multiple processes is never not a problem.  The OS puts up a big wall between them that makes it just about anything hard and expensive.  The code you are using is no exception, iterating running processes is expensive.  Always first consider using threads instead and look for AppDomains in a .NET program, a feature expressly invented to provide the kind of isolation a process can provide but without the cost of a slaying the interop barrier.

If you are committed to a multi-process solution then you almost always need a separate process that acts as an arbiter.  Responsible for ensuring the worker processes get started and doing something meaningful when one of them dies on an unhandled exception.  Which is itself something that's very hard to deal with since there is no good way to get any info about the reason it died and you lost an enormous amount of state.  The typical outcome is a malfunction of the entire app unless you give these processes very simple things to do that you can easily do without.

Such an arbiter process has no problem counting instances cheaply, it can use the Process.Exited event to maintain a counter.  An event instead of having to poll.